# Loading Image Asynchronously

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, image

I have multiple Image files that needs to be loaded when the given option is selected.
By default a an image is already loaded.

When the option is selected, I want to change the image only when the image has completely loaded.

To do this, I am doing an `$http.get` request as follows:

```
$http.get('/public/images/city/amsterdam.jpg').success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    // data loaded
});
```

Once the data has been loaded, I want to assign it to `<img>` or as `background-image`. How can I do this using angularjs or javascript ?

Comment: This seems like a strange way to do it. Is this to save resources when loading images? You could have a `$scope` variable that handles which images to display, and use `ng-if` on `<img>` tags to switch out the `<img>` elements?

Comment: I am using style="background-image:url()" to show the default image. This gets replaced with the new image only when the new image finishes loading so that the element is never without an image. The image sizes are of the order 500-600 KB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JavaScript [image object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement.Image)

```
var myImage = new Image();
myImage.onLoad = function(){
    // data loaded
    // do stuff here, then apply so angular knows.
    $scope.$apply();
};
myImage.src = '/public/images/city/amsterdam.jpg';
```